# How to disable virtual keyboard support for my app?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

Since I've got built-in keypad so I don't need the system-wide virtual keyboard in my WPF app. I set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` for the textbox, but the virtual keyboard thumbnail is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

I answered the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290718/how-can-i-hide-the-little-keyboard-popup-in-windows-mobile-6-5-c/7304421#7304421), but it was for windows mobile 6.5; But i guess it will work on win 7 too.. Below is the code to hide keyboard icon:

```
//Declare Win API method
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindowW", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName)

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

//Call FindWindow and SetWindowPos to hide keyboard icon
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(Nothing, "MS_SIPBUTTON");
SetWindowPos(hWnd, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, &H80);
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136153/how-to-disable-the-little-touch-keyboard-on-windows-edit-controls/8076862#8076862). By setting a Registry value, you can disable the on-screen keyboard thumbnail for a certain application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the virtual keyboard after a specific method, you can do it by just writing this.Focus();